# JavaScript, eccrypto.encrypt() giving an [object object] after hexing the value

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, cryptography, hex

**Intro**:

Hello Community. I have been trying to encrypt a message with the https://www.npmjs.com/package/eccrypto ~ eccrypto.encrypt() function then .toString('hex') the value after encrypting but when I return the hexed value, it gives me [object object]. Why does this happen? I am new to javascript and eccrypto and any insight will be appreciated.

**Relevant Code**:

```
window.encryptMes = async function(data)
{
    //for this you need to get the sender's public key to encrypt the message
    console.log("encryptmes: began");
    var pkey = genPKey();

    if (pkey === null || undefined) 
    {
      
      console.log('You do not have a key pair');

    }

    var encryptedMes = await eccrypto.encrypt(pkey, Buffer.from(data));

    var enMes = encryptedMes.toString('hex');

//question now becomes, WHY IS THIS RETURNING OBJECT OBJECT

    console.log(`encryptedMes returned: ${encryptedMes}`); //could be this since it is not stringified when it goes into celox network
    console.log(`enMes returned: ${enMes}`);
    console.log(`enMes completed successfully`);

    return enMes;
}
```

```
window.genPKey = function()
{
    console.log("getSKey flag: 0");

    const skey = localStorage.getItem('skey');

    const SKey = Buffer.from(skey, 'hex');

    console.log("getSKey flag: 1");

    if(SKey != null || undefined)
    {
        console.log(SKey);

        console.log("getSKey flag: 2");

        const publicKey = eccrypto.getPublic(SKey);
        //encrypt(SKey.publicKey.toHex(), "fuck this is shitty");

        console.log("getSKey flag: 3");

        //localStorage.setItem("pkey", window.btoa(JSON.stringify(publicKey)));

        return publicKey;

    }

    console.log("getSKey flag: alt");

    //genSKey();
    //genPKey();

    return;
}
```

**Focus**:
Why is this returning an [object object] and not something I can store successfully?

Comment: can't test it but you can try to console.dir(encryptedMes) and you'll see the object structure. After that you could select which part of the object you need.

Comment: it is object. not string

Comment: https://github.com/bitchan/eccrypto/blob/master/index.js#L226

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To decrypt the encrypted data you can use a function from eccrypto called `decrypt()`. I wrote these functions to help you understand the possibilities. The encrypt and decrypt function are `asynchronous`, which means we can `await` them in an `async` function. You have to create a public and private key and pass them to the function, that way encryption / decryption is possible.

```js
const eccrypto = require("eccrypto");

// generate keys
const privateKeyA = eccrypto.generatePrivate();
const publicKeyA = eccrypto.getPublic(privateKeyA);
const privateKeyB = eccrypto.generatePrivate();
const publicKeyB = eccrypto.getPublic(privateKeyB);

// function for encrypting the message you pass in
async function encryptingData(pub_key, msg) {
    return await eccrypto.encrypt(pub_key, Buffer.from(msg));
}

// function for decrypting the encrypted message
async function decryptingData(priv_key, encryptedmsg) {
    return await eccrypto.decrypt(priv_key, encryptedmsg);
}

// example main function on how you could use seperate functions.
async function communicate() {
    const message_a = await encryptingData(publicKeyA, 'Message a');
    const message_b = await encryptingData(publicKeyB, 'Message b');

    const decrypted_a = await decryptingData(privateKeyA, message_a);
    const decrypted_b = await decryptingData(privateKeyB, message_b);

    console.log(`Message a encrypted : ${JSON.stringify(message_a)}.`);
    console.log(`Message a decrypted: ${decrypted_a}.`);
    console.log('-------------------------------------')
    console.log(`Message b encrypted : ${JSON.stringify(message_b)}.`);
    console.log(`Message b decrypted : ${decrypted_b}.`);
}

communicate();
```

Comment: And I can store the encrypted message somewhere to decrypt again client sided right?

Comment: That is correct, also on your last question you asked what properties you needed. You have to pass the whole object to the decryption function to make it work, as you can see above. Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

The returned value from an encryption is an object, if you would like to get the specific properties. You could access them with for example: `.mac or .iv`, if you call `JSON.stringify()` on the response, you can see what is inside the objects.

```js
const eccrypto = require("eccrypto");

const privateKey = eccrypto.generatePrivate();
const publickey = eccrypto.getPublic(privateKey);

async function waitFerEncryption() {
    const encrypted = await eccrypto.encrypt(publickey, Buffer.from("msg"));
    console.log();
    console.log(`Stringified: ${JSON.stringify(encrypted)}.`)
    console.log(`Cipher text: ${encrypted.ciphertext}.`)
    console.log(`Mac: ${encrypted.mac}.`)
    console.log(`Iv: ${encrypted.iv}.`)
}

waitFerEncryption();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reponse B4ndy, which object property would I need to store to decrypt the message later with the private key? Is it ciphertext? Or would I need to make a new object with the combination of more properties. Any pointers are appreciated, as I am new to this sort of development and I would like some insight, thank you!